# Syntax Error in FROM Clause - MS. Access

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Here's the code :

```
str = "select * from user where username= '" & txtUsername.Text & "' & password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
perintah = New OleDbCommand(str, conn)
reader = perintah.ExecuteReader()

If reader.Read Then
    MessageBox.Show("login success")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("login failed")
End If
```

Comment: please chain the code block using `CTRL + K`

Comment: have you tried to print `str`?

Comment: By the way, you should not be calling `Read` there. If all you want to know is whether there is data but don't intend to use that data then use the `HasRows` property.  Better still, write a query that returns either a Boolean or count to indicate whether data exists and then call `ExecuteScalar` rather than creating a data reader at all.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the immediate issue is that "user" is a reserved word.  Not 100% sure about Access but it is in most databases.  Try escaping it, i.e. "[user]", and see if that fixes it.

I also just noticed that you are using "&" where "AND" is the operator you need.  I believe that "password" is a reserved word too, so escape that also.

You still have other potential issues there too though.  Using string concatenation to insert values into SQL code is a recipe for disaster, not only potentially causing syntax errors but, even worse, opening you up to SQL injection.  [Read this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) for more information.  In this case specifically, do something like this:

```
str = "SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE username = @username AND [password] = @password"
perintah = New OleDbCommand(str, conn)
perintah.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUsername.Text
perintah.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtPassword.Text
```